# Loop throught directory and subdir

Tags: php

Pls sir, how can I loop through a directory and get the sub-directory name and all the files names so that I can generate a directory try, am trying to build a file manager in php.

I have tried:

```
$dir = new DirectoryIterator(dirname(FILE));
foreach ($dir as $fileinfo) {
    if (!$fileinfo->isDot()) {
        var_dump($fileinfo->getFilename());
    }
}
```

Comment: what have you tried thus far?

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to illustrate the specific problem you're having in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: Have you defined the constant `FILE`? If that's supposed to be a variable, it should be something like `$file`.

Comment: What problem are you having with the code?

Comment: If you want to go into subdirectories you should be using `RecursiveDirectoryIterator`.

Answer (score 0):

You can scan a directory and display the name of files in it using the PHP Code below

```
<?php
    $dir    = 'dir/';
    $files = scandir($dir);

    $totFiles = sizeof($files);

    for($i=2;$i<$totFiles;$i++){
      $name = explode(".",$files[$i]);
      echo "
              $name[0]
      ";
    }
  ?>
```